# Remove equal Key between two JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, algorithm

I have a big problem. I want to create a function that remove equal 'parts' between two JSON files, with the output of function having the same structure, but without the 'equal parts'.

> An example i have a JSON version of a DOM tree and i want keep only the difference between pages (remove nav footer ...)

Example

```
const a = {
  id: '1',
  child: [
    {
     id: '2',
     child: [
       {
        id: '1'
       },
       {
        id: '2'
       }
     ]
    },
    {
     id: '3',
     child: [
       {
        id: '1'
       },
       {
        id: '5'
       }
     ]    
    }
  ]
}
```

And

```
const b = {
  id: '1',
  child: [
    {
     id: '2',
     child: [
       {
        id: '1'
       },
       {
        id: '4'
       }
     ]
    },
    {
     id: '3',
     child: [
       {
        id: '1'
       },
       {
        id: '4'
       }
     ]    
    }
  ]
}
```

With a function

```
diff(a, b)
```

This result

```
{
  id: '1',
  child: [
    {
     id: '2',
     child: [
       {
        id: '2'
       }
     ]
    },
    {
     id: '3',
     child: [
       {
        id: '5'
       }
     ]    
    }
  ]
}
```

I created this based on recursive function

```
const diff = (a, b) => {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {

  }

  if (typeof a === 'object') {
    // ...
    extract(a.child, b.child);
  }
}
```

How do I do this? Is there an npm package? or with JSON Path? I want to create a function that remove the equal 'parts' between two JSON files with the output of the function having the same structure, but without the 'equal parts'.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff.

Comment: i want remove the same part but this packages show me the difference

Comment: Just FYI but those are not json files, those are javascript objects. JSON is JavaScript Object Notation and used to transfer or store javascript objects as strings.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't guarantee the order of the id/value pairs?

I would suggest that you first recursively merge each layer, then go through and remove duplicates.

**Edited With Code from the Recursion function**

```
let c = [] // merged structure
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
   for (let j=0; j<b.length; j++)
   { 
      if (a[i].id === j[i].id) {
         c[i] = { id: a[i].id, child: a[i].child.concat(b[i].child) }
         // next, sort the c[i].child, and
         // loop through c[i].child and recur over any cases where
         // c[i].child[k].id === c[i].child[k+1].id
         // at the end, go back up the chain removing any structs where the 
         // id is a duplicate and has no children left
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I want remove equals object between a and b

Comment: an example i have a JSON version of a DOM tree and i want keep only the difference between page